# HtmlUnit: setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false) is not working

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am performing some test on a website, which is referring to a javascript array `_gaq` and it is not defined anywhere in the page.  I can see the similar exception in Browser but there it is ignoring it. I set the method `setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false)` but still it is throwing

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "_gaq" is not defined.
```

Below is my code

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
wb.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
page = wb.getPage("http://www.axisbank.com/");
HtmlElement el = ((HtmlElement)(page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"form1\"]/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/img").get(0)));
page = el.click();
el = ((HtmlElement)(page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin\"]").get(0)));
System.out.println(el.asText());
page = el.click();
```

Any suggestion how to solve this problem. I tried adding `page.executeScript("var _gaq = []")`, but still failing

Comment: The issue doesn't happen with latest snapshot, which version do you use?

Comment: I am using 2.18 version and this is the lastest in mvn repo

Comment: Please test with the latest [snapshot](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts)

Comment: I am still getting the same error with 2.19-snapshot build

Comment: I retested, and the code you mentioned gives no exception, please post your complete test method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HtmlUnit for pages with serious JavaScript. Its JavaScript engine simply not good enough.

Use Selenium instead.